# FIRESTORE persistent data

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, persistent

talking about firestore persistent data, lets suppose the user does not have any connectivity the first time the app is launched. I add some data to Firestore Database (like userID..), I can get it back with get() method. Now user closes the app.

1. *Next time he will open the app (still without connectivity), will he be able to retrieve data stored previously, just as if it was stored in the way of sharedprefs ?*
   I cannot clearly figure out how to find a proper way to set up an init phasis with persistent data.
2. I have several fragments. Each time one of them is launched, I use "onResume" method to populate my components from data (previously stored in sharedpref). When I set Firestore getData, it takes time to be retrieved. So if the user changes from the current fragment to another one, I have errors about components being null or unreachable at the time the result from database is complete, when connectivity is ON.

   *What would be the best way to implement such "onResume" data refill ?*

UPDATE :

Here is some piece of code in: **MainAvtivity**.kt

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().firestoreSettings.isPersistenceEnabled
        sightingsDatabase = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        docname=FireStoreSetup().setupFB(sightingsDatabase!!,this)
```

a kotlin object class to populate my document :

```
data class Sighting(var userID: String,
                    var sig_wit_situation_type: Int,
                    var sig_env_background_type: Int,
                    var sig_ground_type: Int,
                    var sig_YYYY: String,
                    var sig_MM: String,
                    var sig_DD: String,
                    var sig_time_start: String,
                    var sig_date_time: String,
                    var sig_duration_hms: String,
                    var sig_duration_milli: Int,
                    var sig_weather_full: Int,
                    var sig_temp: Int)
```

in **FireStoreSetup** class : when first init happens ->

```
val sighting = Sighting(deviceId!!,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        strDate.substring(0, 4),
                        strDate.substring(5, 7),
                        strDate.substring(8, 10),
                        strDate.substring(11),
                        strDate,
                        "00:00:00",
                        0,
                        0,
                        0)

                db.collection("users").document(docname!!)
                        .set(sighting)
                        .addOnSuccessListener {
                            Log.d(_tag, "DocumentSnapshot successfully written!")
                            setShared(context,"doc_name",docname!!)}
                        .addOnFailureListener { e -> Log.w(_tag, "Error writing document", e) }
```

then a fun to write data to the server

```
fun addValue(key:String,value:Any?){
        val docData = HashMap<String,Any?>()
        docData.put(key, value)
        FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("users").document(docname!!)
                .set(docData, SetOptions.merge())
    }
```

and

```
 fun readValue(){
        val docRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("users").document(docname!!)
        docRef.addSnapshotListener(object:EventListener<DocumentSnapshot> {
            override fun onEvent(snapshot:DocumentSnapshot?, e:FirebaseFirestoreException?) {
                if (e != null)
                {
                    Log.w("firestore", "Listen failed.", e)
                }
                if (snapshot != null && snapshot.exists())
                {
                    Log.d("firestore", "Current data: " + snapshot.getData())
                    FragmentHome.vars=snapshot.getData()
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.d("firestore", "Current data: null")
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

in **FragmentHome** :

```
companion object {
        val itemsMenu = ArrayList<MenuData>()
        var vars: MutableMap<String,Any>? =null

        fun newInstance(value: Int): FragmentHome {
            val args = Bundle()
            args.putInt("menu", value)
            val fragment = FragmentHome()
            fragment.arguments = args
            return fragment
        }

    }

override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        FireStoreSetup().readValue()
        when (_menu){
            0-> switchRecycler(1,0)
            1-> switchRecycler(0,0)
        }
    }
```

and then from fragmentHome, replacing it with new fragment with firestore values :

```
val situ= vars!!["sig_wit_situation_type"].toString().toInt()
            val env= vars!!["sig_env_background_type"].toString().toInt()
            val grd= vars!!["sig_ground_type"].toString().toInt()
reFrag(FragmentSitu.newInstance(situ,env,grd), 1)
```

where in new FragmentSitu fragment we have :

```
companion object {
        fun newInstance(situ: Int,env: Int,grd: Int): FragmentSitu {
            val args = Bundle()
            args.putInt("sig_wit_situation_type", situ)
            args.putInt("sig_env_background_type", env)
            args.putInt("sig_ground_type", grd)

            val fragment = FragmentSitu()
            fragment.arguments = args
            return fragment
        }
    }
```

and it works with no delays, online and offline, thanks to Franck and docRef.addSnapshotListener.

** There must be a better way to catch `snapshot.getData()` result from within `onEvent(snapshot:DocumentSnapshot?)`,as I would have liked to set my fragment args FragmentSitu.newInstance(situ,env,grd) directly from `snapshot.getData()["situ"]`, `snapshot.getData()["env"]`...

Answer (score 2):

*firebaser here*

Firestore persists the data you write on a device to a local database. So the next time you start the application it will indeed be able to read that same data, even when the device has never been connected to the Firebase servers.

When your app first tries to read data from Firestore it tries to establish a connection to its servers. If you're [using `get()` calls to read the data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document) Firestore will wait for that connection to be established or failed before it returns data. This means it may take quite some time for this initial call. We know that this may lead to unwanted behavior for the users of your app, so we're looking at ways to improve this behavior.

In the meantime, consider [using realtime listeners](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) to read the same data. These listener behave differently in this scenario and will/may provide a result twice:

1. The first snapshot is given straight away and comes from the local cache.
2. The second snapshot is given later, after the client has gotten a response from the cloud database.

Comment: Perfect, thanks Frank ! I will post some code once everything will be set and tested.

Comment: What would be the best way to read 'snapshot.getData()' keys from within the 'onEvent' listener as it is set to be nullable 'snapshot:DocumentSnapshot?', and we need to read for example Int data, wich are not nullable ? Function returns Unit in Kotlin, lest say Void.

Answer (score 0):

As the [offical documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline) says,

> Cloud Firestore supports offline data persistence. This feature caches a copy of the Cloud Firestore data that your app is actively using, so your app can access the data when the device is offline.

But in order to use this feature, you need at least one connection to the dabase. This means that your app must be connected to the internet at least once. After that, you'll be able to write, read, listen to, and query the cached data.

If you want to use data between activities or fragments, i recomand you using either an `Intent` or either `SharedPreferences`, which can hold your data across the whole app.

Comment: Thank you Alex, for now I will change the way init will be set up, as the app needs to be connected at least once. I certainly will need to check if document exists online, with some OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>(), before querying data.

Comment: Yes, that's a good practice to verify a document for existens before doing something with it.